# WordPress local host error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: wordpress, http, localhost, http-status-code-404

I have a localhost website that I was testing and today I got "Error Establishing Database Connection" so I changed the port number from 80 to 8080 but it's not working and I got this 404 error:

[image: 404 error message]

I saw some people mention that I need to edit wp-config.php but Filezilla would not connect to the server either. I am a pretty beginner. Is there any good solution that I can follow or anywhere that I ask for help, hopefully not so expensive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed server port you should visit protocol://host:port/ try to visit [http://localhost:8080/wordpress](https://localhost:8080/wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first, If you have a database connection issue, please change your port back to the default port 80 (This port is used by browsers to receive unencrypted content over the internet. Currently your new URL would be as Mehmet said "http://localhost:8080/wordpress/" which won't solve your problem).

Now to solve the database connection issue, please locate your logs file. For wordpress this is located in the root directory of your wordpress site. I would assume C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\error.log unless you moved your error log. This will tell you what is really wrong with your database connection. It could be a username/password mismatch. Read/Write permissions missing, SQL server crashed/(is not running) or even a corrupted or deleted database.

As for the wp-config.php file, it will be located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-config.php